# catalog_category_view.xml - Layout file not working

Tags: magento2, layout

I have created a `catalog_category_view.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

and placed it in

`app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

or

`app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

**In both cases**, **the layout file has no effect on category page**. BUT Placing the same code in `app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/dafault.xml` works ok.

Any ideas? Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you check after clear cache ?

Comment: yes, I have tried clearing cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this, is adding a `default.xml` file, inside directory `app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/`. It overrides all possible layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Place it in :

```
app/design/frontend/Codazon/company/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

without `/theme`

Update:

```
app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

Comment: That was my mistake in questiuon description. Sorry about that. I changed question text. The correct path is `app/design/frontend/Company/theme/`

Comment: You can see my update.

Comment: thank you. I have already placed the file in `app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` but it's not working. I have mentioned this path in my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Review the proper structure for theming:**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html

**Review Theme Inheritence:**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html

Once you have established that the directory structure is correct -- meaning, you have turned `Codazon/Company/theme` into only two directories, such as `Codazon/theme`, then you should check that theme inheritance is handled correctly.

Comment: That was my mistake in questiuon description. Sorry about that. I changed question text. The correct path is `app/design/frontend/Company/theme/`